# Passing "pure" (class-less) json between Angular and Cosmos DB with .NET

Tags: c#, json, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have json data sitting in Cosmos DB which I want delivered to an angular app.
The angular app can handle various json structures and allow the user to modify the data and push back to Cosmos (via an API - see below).

I am trying to build a simple C# API that will just be used to query data from Cosmos and push the "raw" json back to angular without the need to create classes for each type of json object I am storing. The API is just the mechanism for handing data to Angular from Cosmos and pushing data back into Cosmos from Angular.

I have not found an easy way to do this as all approaches seem to require a structured class object to retrieve the data from Cosmos and save it back.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

-- EDIT --

This is some sample code I was using with dynamic and this works in terms of retrieving the data but it wont serialize into Json in the middleware (see exception below).

```
 public async Task<dynamic> GetItemAsync(string id)
{
  try
  {
    var response = await this._container.ReadItemAsync<dynamic>(id, new PartitionKey(id));
    return response.Resource;
  }
  catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
  {
    return null;
  }

}
```

> [15:12:25 ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the
> request.
> <s:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware>
> System.NotSupportedException: The collection type
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' is not supported.    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.GetDictionaryKeyAndValueFromGenericDictionary(WriteStackFrame&
> writeStackFrame, String& key, Object& value)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.GetDictionaryKeyAndValue(WriteStackFrame&
> writeStackFrame, String& key, Object& value)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleDictionary(JsonClassInfo
> elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter
> writer, WriteStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32
> originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions
> options, WriteStack& state)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object
> value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext
> context, Encoding selectedEncoding)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, IActionResult result)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()

I also tried using System.Text.JSON with JSONDocument but in retrieving the data it complains that it requires a constructor as part of the class?

Comment: you can use dynamic?

Comment: Are you using NewtonSoft.JSON or System.Text.Json? Both can handle this. You can either use JObject in Newtonsoft and ... I think it was JElement (not sure, right now) for System.Text.Json.

Comment: I tried both. NewtonSoft.JSON through an exception trying to deserialize in JSObject. And System.Text.Json complains about a constructor when using JSONDocument

Comment: As for using dynamic...has the same JSObject exception when it tries to serialize before sending the response to the angular app

Comment: Then I think we need some code to look into.

Comment: I just added some further details. let me know if you have any insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` still uses `Newtonsoft.Json` to serialize and deserialize.

Your ASP.NET Core application is using `System.Text.Json`. When working with Cosmos in an ASP.NET Core application, I will switch the solution to use `Newtonsoft.Json` instead of `System.Text.Json`. You can do this by adding this package:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`

- If you are using .NET Core 3.1, use version `3.1.*`
- If you are using .NET5, use version `5.0.*`
- If you are using .NET6, use version
  `6.0.*`

Then, in your `Startup.cs`, inside `ConfigureServices()` method change this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddControllers();
    // ...
}
```

To this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    // ...
}
```

Since you just want the object returned as-is, change your code to this:

```cs
 public async Task<object> GetItemAsync(string id)
{
  try
  {
    var response = await this._container.ReadItemAsync<object>(id, new PartitionKey(id));
    return response.Resource;
  }
  catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
  {
    return null;
  }

}
```

No need to use `dynamic`. Just use `object`.

Comment: Thanks will give this a try and let you know